# Caption changes when using wrapfigures

Tags: graphics, captions, wrapfigure

I'm writting a memoir and I have figures inside. A normal figure looks like that : 
[image: no wrapfigure used]

using the following code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{...}\hspace{0.25cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{...}
\end{center}
\caption{...}\label{...}
\end{figure}
```

But when I use `wrapfigures` like here : 
[image: with wrapfigure]

with the following code :

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{r}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{...}
\end{center}
\vspace{-1cm}
\caption{...}\label{...}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

the caption changes. I mean for a normal figure there is no space between lines in the caption. But for a wrapfigure, there is as much space between lines as in the text + the textsize is bigger for the caption of a wrapfigure. What is wrong ? I want my caption to be compact as the first image.

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example (you can replace the images with, say, `\rule{4cm}{4cm}`. Then is a lot easier for others to help you. For example you could not use the `center` env to center figs inside the `figure` env, though that is not related to this issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting started on the site...

Comment: unrelated to the caption but you just want `\centering` delete the `center` enviornment (which is just adding vertical space) and the negative vspace (which is compensating for the spuriuous center)  presumably you have doublespacing specified somewhere in your document together with specifying single spacing for figures but not wrapfigures

Comment: Yet unrelated, you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package to format those units. `398,17 nm` looks wrong (wrong spacing around the comma). Plus missing spaces at `³Fe₂` and `et3 mTorr`

Comment: @deleif : in France the comma is like the english dot, so in France 398,17 = 398.17 in US/UK. And David Carlisle : it was a bad copy/paste, I corrected it but nothing changes + the thing with the F is a spectroscopic notation. But thanks for the et3 mTorr ;)

Comment: daleif knows about commas:-), he meant that in your image you have no space (as expected)  in `398,24` but a bad space in `398, 17`

Comment: KOMA replaces \caption with \captionbelow or \captionabove.  Try using them instead.

Answer (score -1):

I manually use the command `\linespread{1}\selectfont` before caption and `\linespread{1.4}\selectfont` again after `\end{wrapfigure}`

Comment: this is hardly an answer to the question as posed, presumably you had `\linespread` already earlier which you had not mentioned, and which was the cause of the problem? it is a local setting so you should not need to reset it after the environment. normally it is better to use setspace or a similar package that manages setting/resetting the line spacing in figures rather than using `\linspread` directly.